# Do I add the files in my migrations folder to my live Django server?

Tags: python, django, git, digital-ocean

I'm going to push my offline Django project to Bitbucket, and then push that repo to my live Django server. My question is, do I exclude the **contents** in my migrations folders? And then perform `makemigrations` and `migrate` on my live server (Ubuntu/DigitalOcean) after the repo has been pushed to there?

Comment: yes, do fresh migration on the live server

Comment: Do you know what pattern I add in my `.gitignore` to exclude the **contents** of the migrations folders?

Comment: yes, for all the apps

Comment: Are you saying to exclude the `migrations` folders aswell? (not just the contents of the folders)?

Comment: yeah you can do that, thats better than mentioning all the file names, just remove the migration folder totally,

Comment: Ok thanks. So the `migrations` folders will automatically be created when I perform the migrations tasks on the live server?

Comment: yes, once you run makemigrations for the apps, the migration folder will be auto generated in all the apps folder

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that you already have too many migrations files you can squash them: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing

Answer (score 0):

No. Migrations are integral parts of your source code, they must be kept in your repo and deployed as any other part of your source.

Remember that migrations are not restricted to generated schema change operations - some schema changes cannot be correctly generated by `makemigrations` and have to be manually coded, and also data migrations can only be handcoded.

Comment: So are you saying not to add any `/migrations` to my `.gitignore` file? So I should push my migrations folders (which are populated with historical migrations) to my new, live Django remote server?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying your migrations are __integral part_ of your project's source code , must be kept under revision control, and must be deployed (and passed) when you update your production server.  You can of course squash them when preparing a release to avoid having too many migrations.